# MySQL count from different Tables

Tags: mysql, count

### Table A

```
Status
1
1
1
2
2
3
```

### Table B

```
Status
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
```

How to Get following Result Table

### Result Table

```
Status    Count
1           5
2           6
3           3
```

Help me to build SQL Query to get Count in Result Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT STATUS, COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT STATUS FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL 
SELECT STATUS FROM TABLE2) un
GROUP BY STATUS
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b1958/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this

SELECT Status, COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT a.Status FROM TableA AS a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.Status FROM TableB AS b) UN
GROUP BY Status
```